# property does not exist on type {} angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I am using `topojson` to convert a `json` file to a `geofile` to be read by `d3js` geo api; however, typescript is giving me an error stating that `objects does not exist on type {}` for the data returned by the callback function and I'm not really sure how to resolve this problem

```
d3Data.json('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vida-public/geo/world-topo-min.json', function(error, world) {
    if (error) throw error;

    svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
        //Property objects does not exist on type {} 
        .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
        .attr("class", "land")
        .attr("d", path);

    svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
        //Property objects does not exist on type {} 
        .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
        .attr("class", "boundary")
        .attr("d", path);
  });
```

Comment: Try to use worlds['objects'] instead of world.objects or make sure your world variable is type of Array<any>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the type of `world` parameter to `any` like this:

`function (error, world: any) {...}`

As noted by @Duncan, it would be better to cast the `world` property to a specific type, that you expect:

```
export interface World {
  // not sure about types of `land` and `countries`
  objects: { land: any, countries: any };
}

function (error, world: World) {...}
```

Comment: Or much better would be to set `world` to an actual type. Using `any` as a parameter type is generally a bad idea.

Comment: True, will add a note about that.